# Wi-fi turns off randomly

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, wireless-networking

Wi-Fi in my laptop (intel wireless3945 abg) turns off randomly (hardware turn off) it disappear from hardware list and its light is going off. I think that it is going down when my computer starts to save power and turning it off for a moment, then it cannot bring it back again.

When I click on button that turn off / on wi fi. I can turn off but then I can not turn on. Sometimes option find new hardware in Hardware View helps and wi fi is being reinitialized (but it is rarely thing).

Do you have and Idea what should I do I have drivers from 15/09/09. Version 13.0.0.107.

I unchecked option that lets turning off wi fi in Hardware View under Power Management (Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power).

The same on windows xp and windows 7

I think that it might be some problem with drivers because when I restart my computer wifi sometime is working and sometime not. But when I hibernate / dehibernate it always works.

Laptop model hp 6710s

Comment: Turning off all power options under BIOS and in Windows7 did the job (under hardware tab and under power plan)

Comment: I put in new wireless card and everything works correctly so it must be some hardware malfunction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been down this road before with a Thinkpad.  I had to go line by line through all the power and wireless config areas.  Eventually I had everything relating to any type of wireless power saving and speed throttling disabled and then it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to turn off the option in the BIOS if there is one. I believe that this will overwrite any commands that windows makes. But then again I may be wrong.

Comment: If you aren't sure, its normally better to leave a comment instead of an answer.  We are hoping answers will be confident responses (with detail), not guesses :)